# My Laravel Homestead doesn't work

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm having problem to understand how to run my website using vagrant and Laravel Homestead environment.

I added `laravel/homestead` box without any problems. Then I ran `vagrant init laravel/homestead` and it worked too.

I managed to create Homestead.yaml and here's what it contains:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/www
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: project.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/code/project

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

`vagrant up` runs correctly, but I don't know how to access my website. I added `192.168.10.10   project.dev` to my `/etc/hosts`.

I want to keep my project at `~/www/project`. First thing that I didn't understand from the docs is, what is the folder at sites / map / to setting supposed to be? My local folder or a folder in the virtual environment?

The next thing I don't understand is why when I do `vagrant ssh` and then `ls`, I don't see any files, even though there's `index.php` at my `~/www/project`. I thought they are going to be synchronized automatically.

When I go to `project.dev` in the browser, it timeouts. I tried `project.dev:8000` as well and `192.168.10.10`, but nothing works.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting the folders parameter, also your indentation should be with spaces and not with tabs, thats the way yaml works, everything else seems to be fine but try to make it with something similar to this one

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/www/project
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: project.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/code/project/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

Comment: My indentation is spaces, not tabs. I realized that I need this `folder` parameter, so I added it. It still doesn't work though.

Comment: Remember, in the sites section, afther you declare map: project.dev point to the public folder `to: home/vagrant/code/project/public`

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the folder share settings in you're `homestead.yaml` file.

Try adding

```
folders:
    - map: ~/www/project
      to: /home/vagrant/code
```

Look at the docs here 
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead#configuring-homestead under **Configuring Shared Folders**

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the common issue that someone new to Laravel Homestead is facing.

Laravel Homestead basically provides an image that gets a VM ready for Laravel development. The yaml config on "sites" is basically use to configure Nginx - **it does not install a Laravel project on the path specified**.

So for a new homestead VM, you just have to ssh into your Homestead VM, and type and run this:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

Once done, on you /home/vagrant/code folder (in the VM, not your host), type and run this:

```
laravel new project
```

Where the "project" is the name given to your new project. Since your yaml is already configured to "project", the above command will work fine. Obviously, this is clearly not the only way to get Laravel as you can use composer create-project to install Laravel directly.

Once done, you should be able to visit http://project.dev on your host's browser, if your host file is configured with this added entry:

```
192.168.10.10<tab>project.dev
```

Alternatively, you can configure your host file to be

```
127.0.0.1<tab>project.dev
```

Which you can then view on your host's browser via http://project.dev:8000

Hope the above explains clear enough. Enjoy!

Comment: I already managed to make it work, it was a problem with folders, not with hosts. I didn't understand how does the mapping exactly work like.